# Kafka usage on Google appengine to push messages-Is it possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-kafka

I am trying to push messages from webApplication server hosted on Google AppEngine to the kafka cluster running on my local machine. Is there any one who did this? I am facing an issue while creating KafkaProducer instance to send the messages. I am using Kafka_0.8.2. It gives error, "javax.management.ObjectName is a restricted class" and which as per AppEngine's whitelist, its restricted. What is the alternative for this? Can anyone answer? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately GAE has plenty of limitations, including the use of certain classes and the ways you can connect to the outer world (ej sockets) does Kafka provide any API you can reach through http/xmpp or a raw socket connection?

Comment: Yeah.I have seen many such issues people are facing with GAE. Kafka has other clients also like Http which I am trying now. Thanks for reply.